# keydown event not working in bootstrapped Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, key

I am new to extension development. I am trying to trigger an action on a `keydown` event in my bootstrapped Firefox extension, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Here is my bootstrap.js code:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

function watchWindows(callback) {

    function watcher(window) {
    try {

      let {documentElement} = window.document;
      if (documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype") == "navigator:browser")
        callback(window);
    }
    catch(ex) {}
    }


     function runOnLoad(window) {

    window.addEventListener("load", function runOnce() {
      window.removeEventListener("load", runOnce, false);
      watcher(window);
    }, false);
  }

  // Add functionality to existing windows
  let windows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
  while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
    // Only run the watcher immediately if the window is completely loaded
    let window = windows.getNext();
    if (window.document.readyState == "complete")
      watcher(window);
    // Wait for the window to load before continuing
    else
      runOnLoad(window);
  }

  // Watch for new browser windows opening then wait for it to load
  function windowWatcher(subject, topic) {
    if (topic == "domwindowopened")
      runOnLoad(subject);
  }
  Services.ww.registerNotification(windowWatcher);

  // Make sure to stop watching for windows if we're unloading
  unload(function() Services.ww.unregisterNotification(windowWatcher));
}

/**
* Save callbacks to run when unloading. Optionally scope the callback to a
* container, e.g., window. Provide a way to run all the callbacks.
*
* @usage unload(): Run all callbacks and release them.
*
* @usage unload(callback): Add a callback to run on unload.
* @param [function] callback: 0-parameter function to call on unload.
* @return [function]: A 0-parameter function that undoes adding the callback.
*
* @usage unload(callback, container) Add a scoped callback to run on unload.
* @param [function] callback: 0-parameter function to call on unload.
* @param [node] container: Remove the callback when this container unloads.
* @return [function]: A 0-parameter function that undoes adding the callback.
*/
function unload(callback, container) {
  // Initialize the array of unloaders on the first usage
  let unloaders = unload.unloaders;
  if (unloaders == null)
    unloaders = unload.unloaders = [];

  // Calling with no arguments runs all the unloader callbacks
  if (callback == null) {
    unloaders.slice().forEach(function(unloader) unloader());
    unloaders.length = 0;
    return;
  }

  // The callback is bound to the lifetime of the container if we have one
  if (container != null) {
    // Remove the unloader when the container unloads
    container.addEventListener("unload", removeUnloader, false);

    // Wrap the callback to additionally remove the unload listener
    let origCallback = callback;
    callback = function() {
      container.removeEventListener("unload", removeUnloader, false);
      origCallback();
    }
  }

  // Wrap the callback in a function that ignores failures
  function unloader() {
    try {
      callback();
    }
    catch(ex) {}
  }
  unloaders.push(unloader);

  // Provide a way to remove the unloader
  function removeUnloader() {
    let index = unloaders.indexOf(unloader);
    if (index != -1)
      unloaders.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return removeUnloader;
}

/* library */

const Utils = (function() {

    const sbService = Cc['@mozilla.org/intl/stringbundle;1']
                         .getService(Ci.nsIStringBundleService);
    const windowMediator = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
                              .getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);


    let setAttrs = function(widget, attrs) {
        for (let [key, value] in Iterator(attrs)) {
            widget.setAttribute(key, value);
        }
    };

    let getMostRecentWindow = function(winType) {
        return windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow(winType);
    };

    let exports = {
        setAttrs: setAttrs,
        getMostRecentWindow: getMostRecentWindow,
    };
    return exports;
})();



let ResponseManager = (function() {

    const obsService = Cc['@mozilla.org/observer-service;1']
                          .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);

    const RESPONSE_TOPIC = 'http-on-examine-response';

    let observers = [];

    let addObserver = function(observer) {
        try {
            obsService.addObserver(observer, RESPONSE_TOPIC, false);
        } catch(error) {
            trace(error);
        }
        observers.push(observers);
    };

    let removeObserver = function(observer) {
        try {
            obsService.removeObserver(observer, RESPONSE_TOPIC, false);
        } catch(error) {
            trace(error);
        }
    };

    let destory = function() {
        for (let observer of observers) {
            removeObserver(observer);
        }
        observers = null;
    };

    let exports = {
        addObserver: addObserver,
        removeObserver: removeObserver,
        destory: destory,
    };
    return exports;
})();

/* main */

let ReDisposition = function() {

    let respObserver;

    respObserver = {

        observing: false,

        observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
            try {
                let channel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
                this.override(channel);
            } catch(error) {
                trace(error);
            }
        },

        start: function() {
            if (!this.observing) {
                ResponseManager.addObserver(this);
                this.observing = true;
            }
        },
        stop: function() {
            if (this.observing) {
                ResponseManager.removeObserver(this);
                this.observing = false;
            }
        },
        refresh: function() {
            this.start();
        },

        re: /^\s*attachment/i,

        re2: /^\s*text/i,

        override: function(channel) {

            if(disablePlugin)
            {
               try {
               let contentHeader;
               contentHeader = channel.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
               if (this.re2.test(contentHeader)) 
               return;
               channel.setResponseHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment", false);
               return;
               }
                catch(error) {
                return;
                }       
            }

            // check if have header
            let header;
            try {
                header = channel.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            } catch(error) {
                return;
            }

            // override to inline
            if (this.re.test(header)) {
                channel.setResponseHeader('Content-Disposition', header.replace(this.re, "inline"), false);
                return;
            }

        }
    };



    let initialize = function() {

        respObserver.refresh();
    };
    let destory = function() {

        respObserver.stop();
    };

    let exports = {
        initialize: initialize,
        destory: destory,
    }
    return exports;

};

/* bootstrap entry points */

let reDisposition;
var disablePlugin = false;
let install = function(data, reason) {};
let uninstall = function(data, reason) {};

let startup = function(data, reason) {

    reDisposition = ReDisposition();
    reDisposition.initialize();
    function onwindow(window) {
        function onkeydown(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 70)
            {
            disablePlugin = true;
            }
            else
            {
            disablePlugin = false;
            }

        }
        function onkeyup(e) {

            disablePlugin = false;

        }
        // Bootstrapped add-ons need to clean up after themselves!
        function onunload() {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", onkeypress);
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", onkeypress);
        }
        window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", onkeyup);
        unload(onunload, window);
    }
    watchWindows(onwindow);


};

let shutdown = function(data, reason) {
    reDisposition.destory();
};
```

Comment: Please don't radically change your question after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `window` in a `bootstrap.js` scope. `bootstrap.js` is essentially a standalone code module (that is running in a Sandbox, but that's just an implementation detail). It will run only once per application, not once per window.

When developing [bootstrapped add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions), you have to enumerate existing and watch for new windows yourself and "attach" to them as needed. See e.g. the [`watchWindows` boilerplate](https://github.com/Mardak/restartless/blob/watchWindows/bootstrap.js).

Here is an example. It assumes you're using the `watchWindows` boilerplate:

```
function startup(data, reason) {
    // Callback function called for each browser window (browser.xul)
    function onwindow(window) {
        function onkeydown(e) {
            // XXX: Your code here.
        }
        // Bootstrapped add-ons need to clean up after themselves!
        function onunload() {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", onkeypress);
        }
        window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown);
        unload(onunload, window);
    }

    // Will also fire for existing windows once and upon each new window.
    watchWindows(onwindow);
}
```

Developing bootstrapped add-ons isn't really something I'd recommend when you're new to Firefox add-ons, XUL/XPCOM and the mozilla platform in general. You probably should check out XUL overlay-based add-ons or the Add-on SDK.

Comment: i highly recommend the addon SDK, if it allows implementing what you need/want. You will definitively save a lot of time, in comparison with XUL based addons

Comment: @nmaler I have updated the code, is it not possible at all to listen to keyboard events in the above code.

Comment: It appears that you just copied some random code that doesn't really solve your problem... and then don't even attempt to use it. I linked `watchWindows`, which may actually help you install a keypress handler. I'll try add an example to my answer.

Comment: @nmaler Thanks a lot but it is still not working, I have uploaded the whole source, I am trying to prevent modification of header on key press. Please help me with this. On key down I want to disable the header modification and restore it on key up.

Comment: You actually need to copy the `watchWindows` boilerplate into your code! That is the `watchWindows` and `unload functions`. Or write some yourself, if you don't like the licensing...

Comment: @nmaler Thanks a lot, it is working, but the key up event doesn't seem to work properly. I have uploaded the whole code, I still can't believe that I had to add around 150 lines of code just for event handling. Is their any thing which I added extra from the watch windows code.

Comment: "It is working": I consider this question answered now. Please ask new question for new problems, with a detailed description (and "doesn't seem to work properly" isn't really "detailed")